# FBX file imports and textures

Tags: texturing, .fbx

Starting to use Blender again after a couple of years. Currently trying to import some free model downloads that include FBX files. I thought that just importing these would also import and apply the texture files but the objects do not appear to be rendering.

One of these files is here:

[birch-bush](https://www.dropbox.com/t/3pdiRVk6qKJpqVLz)

I have tried all the files in a single folder, the fbx file in source and images in textures, (all with "image search" ticked in the Import) and none seem to apply the images.

[image]

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the FBX file you provided doesn't include any materials, or not in a way readable by Blender. But we can rebuild it easily.

First, make sure you have the addon Node Wrangler enabled under the menu Edit > Preferences > Addons tab, search "Node Wrangler" and make sure it is checked ON.

Then, open the Shader Editor (you can use the popover menu in the top left corner of an area or put your mouse in the timeline editor and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>).

Click the New button in the middle of the header to create a new material.

Select the Principled BSDF node, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, navigate to your model's textures location, select them all and press enter. It should have imported all your images and plugged them into the Principled BSDF. We just need a few tweaks:

Look for the node named "Base Color", drag its Alpha output to the Principled BSDF's Alpha input.
Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Color > Mix and put that node on the Base Color node's color noodle, it should automatically plug it on it. Change its Blend Mode from Mix to Multiply, set the factor to 1, and plug the Ambient Occlusion node's Color output to the B input.

If you use Eevee rendered, in the sidebar > Options tab > Settings panel, change the Blender Mode and Shadow Mode to Alpha Hashed.

The final result should be this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked as you described. Just want to understand the actions of the mixrgb node in this case. What does Multiply actually do to the mix of those 2 images and what is Factor 1? I can see that the shape in the AO ensures the coloured image only shows that image and the background is totally transparent. I assume Factor of 1 means total transparency rather than a percentage of opaqueness (I think???) but what is the difference between Multiply and the other options?